# How do I implode this ACF array with commas

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to show a list of linked items separated by commas, excluding the comma from the last item.  I can't seem to get the syntax right

```
<?php  $prerequisite = get_field('prerequisites'); ?>
<?php if( $prerequisite ):  ?>
    <li> Prerequisites: 

    <?php foreach( $prerequisite as $prerequisites ): ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prerequisites->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($prerequisites->ID ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can use counter variable for this.  You need to use two variables. `$lengh` which has total  number of array in `$prerequisite` using `count($prerequisite)` and other variable is `$counter` which is set to 1 by default. Check `$counter` and `$length`, if they are same don't show comma and else show to comma and increment `$counter` by 1 in a loop. Other option is to use `implode()` function.

Answer (score 1):

**try this code**

using *trim* function commas value manage and you can find **trim** function detail here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

```
<?php 
$prerequisite = get_field('prerequisites');
if( $prerequisite ):  
  ?>
  <li> Prerequisites: 
  <?php 
  $nvtest = "";
  foreach( $prerequisite as $prerequisites ): 
      $nvtest.='<a href="'.get_permalink( $prerequisites->ID ).'">'.get_the_title($prerequisites->ID ).'</a> ,';
  endforeach; 
  echo trim($nvtest," ,");
  ?>
  </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: A better explanation than *try this code* would help.

Comment: What is problem with my code ?


why my answer is down vote?

Downvoter please tell me

Comment: There is an explenation just above here posted by Nigel.

Comment: That works but it outputs twice for some reason, once without commas and then once with comma

Comment: @StephanieOrtiz what is twice output explain in details

Comment: Hi @StephanieOrtiz,
if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work